# Is it possible to update to a document with array of fields in elasticsearch using update_by_query API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with the following content in all the documents in an index:

```
   "universities": {
                      "number": 1,
                      "state": [
                         {
                            "Name": "michigan",
                            "country": "us",
                            "code": 5696
                         }
                      ]
                   }
```

I want to update all the documents in the index like this

```
  "universities": {
                      "number": 1,
                      "state": [
                         {
                            "Name": "michigan",
                            "country": "us",
                            "code": 5696
                         },                          
                         {
                            "Name": "seatle",
                            "country": "us",
                            "code": 5695
                         }
                      ]
                   }
```

IS this can be possible using update_by_query in elasticsearch 2.4.1?

I tried the below query:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "for(i in ctx._source.univeristies.state){i.name=Text}",
    "params": {
      "Text": "seatle"
    }
  }
}
```

but is appending the name to existing one rather than creating a new one in a list.

Comment: It's not possible to have two fields with the same name `state`. Are you sure that the `seattle` state shouldn't be another sibling object in the `state` array?

Comment: yes,val it is another sibling of `state`

Comment: then you should correct your question

Comment: Val i had corrected the question is this can be possible using update_by_query?

Comment: still not good, I've fixed it

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible with update by query, simply append the new state at the end of the state array in a script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this script instead:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.universities.state.add(new_state)",
    "params": {
      "new_state": {
          "Text": "Seattle",
          "country": "us",
          "code": 5695
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For later versions of ES (6+), the query looks like this instead:

```
"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.universities.state.add(params.new_state)",
    "params": {
      "new_state": {
          "Text": "Seattle",
          "country": "us",
          "code": 5695
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..val . How fast it will happen when a index consists of 5k-6k documents.

Comment: It's hard to tell, just try ;-)

Comment: Why you didnt used `for` loop in inline script as i did in my question?Whether it will used only to update a single field?

Comment: Your goal was only to append a new object, why a for loop?

Comment: Suppose if i want to update a particular field then i need a `for` loop right ?Other than that no need of it.Thanks